# Partial template specialization for type

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, specialization

I have a class `vec_base` defined like so:

```
template<typename T, std::size_t Size>
class vec_base;
```

and I would like to specialize it so that

```
vec_base<float, /* any multiple of 4 */>
```

and

```
vec_base<double, /* any multiple of 2 */>
```

can have specific members independently as apposed to, say

```
vec_base<int, 6>
```

which would have generic members that I have already defined

I'm having a tough time implementing this because of the lenient size allowed (any multiple of 4 or 2) if it were specifically 2 or 4 I know I could perform full specialization, but that isn't the case :/

How would I go about this? Any help at all is appreciated, I always love learning new language techniques!

---

### EDIT

okay so I have this so far:

```
template<std::size_t Size>
struct is_div_by_4{static const bool value = (Size % 4 == 0);};
// have to define because of template requirements
// about not being dependent on other parameters

template<typename T, std::size_t Size, bool is_special>
class vec_base;

template<typename T, std::size_t Size>
class vec_base<T, Size, false>{
    // generic implementation
};

teplate<std::size_t Size>
class vec_base<float, Size, is_div_by_4<Size>::value>{
    // Special implementation (for sse, it's no secret)
};
```

but I haven't compiled it yet and I know it won't work, so please don't point that out; it's just what I have so far incase you thought I was just deferring my own work to SO.

Comment: No need to be so deprecating about your attempt - it almost works!

Comment: **almost** works haha I just didn't want scrutiny about that

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Simple solution

The most simple technique would be using [`std::enable_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if) and [`std::same`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/type_traits/is_same/) similar to  what you did:

```
template<typename T, std::size_t Size, typename U = void>
class vec_base { /* implement me generically */ };

template<typename T, std::size_t Size>
class vec_base<T, Size, typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<T, float>::value && Size % 4 == 0>::type>
{ /* implement me with 10% more awesome-sauce */ };

template<typename T, std::size_t Size>
class vec_base<T, Size, typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<T, double>::value && Size % 2 == 0>::type>
{ /* implement me with pepper instead */ };
```

#### Why the `typename U = void` can be avoided

The idea behind `std::enable if` is something called the SFINAE principle, which basically states that whenever instantiating a template does not work, the compiler will not error out, but instead just remove that one definition from all overload sets and similar name resolutions.

The implementation behind `std::enable_if` specializes the class template, so that `std::enable_if<false>` does not contain a member `type` at all. Therefore using that type member will cause an error that (due to SFINAE) removes this specialization from consideration.

Since your template already contains a type parameter, you could instead use that type parameter, since the `std::enable_if<true>::type` is actually the same as its second parameter, a type parameter that only defaults to `void`, but can of course be set.

Therefore, you can remove the last template parameter in the generic implementation completely and instead specialize like so:

```
template<typename T, std::size_t Size>
class vec_base<typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<T, float>::value && Size % 4 == 0, float>::type, Size>
{ /* implement me with 10% more awesome-sauce */ };
```

#### Why the `typename T` and `std::same` are not necessary

From this you can also see that you could remove the `typename T` of your specializations and drop the usage of `std::is_same`. `T` must always be a specific type after all...

```
template<std::size_t Size>
class vec_base<typename std::enable_if<Size % 4 == 0, float>::type, Size>
{
    friend vec_base operator+(vec_base const& lhs, vec_base const& rhs)
    { /* do some additions */
        return lhs;
    }
};
```

Adding more operators outside of the class is fairly simple:

```
// works for all vec_base variants
template<typename T, std::size_t Size>
vec_base<T, Size> operator-(vec_base<T, Size> const& lhs, vec_base<T, Size> const& rhs)
{ /* do some subtractions */
    return lhs;
}

// works only for the specialization float, divisible by 4
template<std::size_t Size>
typename std::enable_if<Size % 4 == 0, vec_base<float, Size>>::type
operator-(vec_base<float, Size> const& lhs, vec_base<float, Size> const& rhs)
{ /* do some salty computations */
    return lhs;
}
```

This actually works because the second version is strictly more restricted than the first version (every argument group that works with the special function also works for the generic one - but the generic one has some for which the special one will not work).

#### Fixing your attempt

Although you seem rather down about your attempt, here is how to adapt it to work as well (note that this solution is far more convoluted than the one shown above):

```
template<typename T, std::size_t Size, int mode =
    (std::is_same<T, float>::value && Size % 4 == 0) ? 1
    : (std::is_same<T, double>::value && Size % 2 == 0) ? 2
    : 0>
struct vec_base;

template<typename T, std::size_t Size>
struct vec_base<T, Size, 0>
{ static void hello() { ::std::cout << "hello all\n"; } };

template<std::size_t Size>
struct vec_base<float, Size, 1>
{ static void hello() { ::std::cout << "hello 4 floats\n"; } };

template<std::size_t Size>
struct vec_base<double, Size, 2>
{ static void hello() { ::std::cout << "hello 2 doubles\n"; } };
```

You would call it like so:

```
vec_base<float, 2>::hello(); // hello all
vec_base<float, 4>::hello(); // hello 4 floats
```

Comment: I already know I can do this, I need to specialize it so that when `T == float && Size % 4 == 0` are true and `T == double && Size % 2 == 0` are true :L

Comment: Even after the second edit, I want to be able to write `vec_base<float, 4>` and `vec_base<double, 4>` and have the methods be different for those 2 classes. I already implement my class like you do in your post currently :P `enable_if` and all

Comment: That's more like it! I haven't used `is_same` before

Comment: @CoffeeandCode I only read your comment after I fixed up your code to what I thought you wanted to do ;)

Comment: Help the slow guy. Your logic on this: `class vec_base<typename std::enable_if<Size % 4 == 0, float>::type, Size>` seems wrong. Where in the OP's post does it say anything about *non*-float and *non*-double types **not** being allowed a `Size` that is a multiple of 4 or 2 respectively? I.e. the posted question indicates those two types *must* be of those multiples. It says nothing about no *other* types being allowed to do so as well. I submit then, that the type **is** necessary.

Comment: @gha.st sorry, I have to downvote this: putting all your special conditions for the specializations into a parameter of the generic version is a no-no. Suppose you get 128-bit long doubles, then you need to modify your generic code instead of adding a new specialization.

Comment: Or its waaay to late for me to be reading template expansions. Been a long day. Beautiful code, btw. Just not clear in my head whether it money. If it is, I profusely apologize. I didn't down vote this, just wanted to make sure I was reading from the right direction.

Comment: @TemplateRex I assume you are talking about the version that merely makes the OPs solution work. Its purpose is to show how the technique the OP used can be made to *work*, not to improve upon the solution presented before

Comment: Sorry about that, could you make a token edit so i can remove the downvote?

Comment: @TemplateRex I added a note to make it more obvious ;)

Comment: God damn it. Now that I've taken the specialization into the hands of the first type parameter it's either extremely ugly to overload operators or extremely difficult. Think I might go back to a trait :/

Comment: @CoffeeandCode have a look at the example which overloads `operator+` as an example - does that help?

Comment: Well, I wanted to overload it as a free-standing function rather than a member of friend function; I already know I can overload pretty easily as a member

Comment: @CoffeeandCode A `friend` when defined like this actually *is* a free function of the closest surrounding namespace (meaning it will not be a member, but instead be found by ADL). I will however add another example, so you can see that it remains simple even when not defining it inside the class (be it member or friend)

Answer (score 2):

Simpler yet:

```
template<typename T, std::size_t Size>
class vec_base
{
  public: vec_base() {
      std::cout << "I am generic, my size is " << Size << std::endl;
  }
};

template<std::size_t Size>
class vec_base<typename std::enable_if<Size % 4 == 0, float>::type, Size>
{
  public: vec_base() {
      std::cout << "I am specialized for float, my size is " << Size << std::endl;
  }
};

template<std::size_t Size>
class vec_base<typename std::enable_if<Size % 2 == 0, double>::type, Size>
{
  public: vec_base() {
      std::cout << "I am specialized for double, my size is " << Size << std::endl;
  }
};
```

Comment: Pretty sure this will give a compile error about dependent templates or some shiz because you're comparing `Size` inside the template that it is defined in, that's why in my original question I declared the `is_div_by_4` `struct`

Comment: Works for me. Note it works exactly the same way as in the other answer, only without the additional dummy type argument. The error would happen if `Size % 2` or something more complex were passed directly to the generic `vec_base`. But here it's passed to `enable_if`.

Comment: It definitely should work - but it does not seem quite as obvious *why* it works ;)

Comment: Hmm, I was just guessing because I've already tried passing it straight to a `bool` in the template and that complained before

Comment: You probably violated 14.5.4/9: "A partially specialized **non-type** argument expression shall not involve a template parameter **of the partial specialization** except when the argument expression is a simple identifier." That is, you had something like `template<size_t Size> class vec_base<double, Size, Size%2==0>`. This is a no-no. But you can have `template<size_t Size> class vec_base<double, Size, some_template<Size%2==0>::type>` because you are passing a **type** argument here.

Answer (score 2):

### Encapsulate your specialness in a type trait

I would go for a `is_special<T, N>` type trait that gives `std::false_type` for all types that do not fit into your SSE solution, and `std::true_type` otherwise.

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

// test whether a vector of floating points fits into B bits SSE solution
template<typename T, std::size_t N, std::size_t B = 128>
struct is_special
: 
    std::integral_constant<bool, 
        std::is_floating_point<T>::value && 8 * sizeof(T) * N == B
    > 
{};
```

I generally don't like putting raw conditions in my template specializations that make use of such traits, as this can lead to less maintainable code (especially if you re-use the type trait anywhere else).

### Specialize your template using `enable_if`

You can then do a `std::enable_if` on this type trait

```
template<typename, std::size_t, typename = void>
class vec_base
{
public:
    static void print() { std::cout << "vec_base<T, N>\n"; };    
};

template<std::size_t N>  
class vec_base<float, N, typename std::enable_if<is_special<float, N>::value>::type>
{
public:
    static void print() { std::cout << "vec_base<float, 4 * K>\n"; };    
};

template<std::size_t N> 
class vec_base<double, N, typename std::enable_if<is_special<double, N>::value>::type>
{
public:
    static void print() { std::cout << "vec_base<double, 2 * K>\n"; };    
};
```

Note that the generic template does not need to know about the kind of special conditions that you use for the specializations. This is a manifestion of the Open/Closed principle: your code is closed for modification, but open for extensions. For 128 bit long doubles, just add a new specialization.

### Testing the code in practice

You can call this code like this:

```
int main()
{
    vec_base<int, 6>::print();    // vec_base<T, N>
    vec_base<float, 1>::print();  // vec_base<T, N>
    vec_base<float, 4>::print();  // vec_base<float, 4 * K>
    vec_base<double, 1>::print(); // vec_base<T, N>
    vec_base<double, 2>::print(); // vec_base<double, 2 * K>
}
```

[**Live Example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/db8da569bba7ea27) that prints the commented lines above. It's important to test both the cases you want and the cases you don't want to call SSE code.